# Magento 2 - prevent the 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded issue?

Tags: magento2, orders, deadlock

Does any have any idea to prevent the 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded issue?

```
main.CRITICAL: Saving order 0002347423 failed: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; 
try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `sales_invoice_item` (`parent_id`, `base_price`, `tax_amount`, `base_row_total`, `row_total`,
 `price_incl_tax`, `base_tax_amount`, `base_price_incl_tax`, `qty`, `base_cost`, `price`, `base_row_total_incl_tax`, `row_total_incl_tax`, `product_id`, 
`order_item_id`, `description`, `sku`, `name`, 
`discount_tax_compensation_amount`, `base_discount_tax_compensation_amount`, `weee_tax_applied`, `weee_tax_applied_amount`, 
`weee_tax_applied_row_amount`, 
`weee_tax_disposition`, `weee_tax_row_disposition`, `base_weee_tax_applied_amount`, `base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt`, 
`base_weee_tax_disposition`, 
`base_weee_tax_row_disposition`) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [] []
```

If anyone has any solution for the issue above, then please help me to solve it.

Comment: if you have a timeout issue to save a simple order i suspect you have an other error

Comment: @Claims We're not facing this issue error every time. Will face this issue sometimes.

Comment: Hey. @MKPatel did you find a solution for it?